# What to do after 2 commits in the wrong branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I had a repo that has branch `master`, `branch1` and `branch2` that are *all* pointing to the same commit (let's call it `aaaaaa1`).

I wanted to checkout `branch1` and make some changes. However, I forgot. Instead, I did 2 commits to master (`aaaaaa2` and `aaaaaa3`, *without* pushing anything anywhere (this is only local).

What do I run so make it so that `master` is reset to `aaaaaa1` and `branch1` is set to `aaaaaa3` as it should have been in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
```

Here you have `branch1` pointing to `aaaaaa3`... Then:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard aaaaaa1
```

And here you have `master` pointing back to `aaaaaa1`

---

edit:

[Rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) takes commits from specified branch (in this case `master`) that are not in the current branch (in this case `branch1`) and commits them here.

[Reset --hard](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) can be used to just empty working tree as you used it alredy. Also, with commitID parameter (in this case `aaaaaa1`), you can reset your branch to specific commit as if the commits after that were never there.

In the question you stated you didn't push the commits to remote server, so this paragraph doesn't need to concern you now... But be careful when using `reset --hard` on code that you already pushed to remote server. You would have to push with -f (force) parameter because you are basically changing the branch structure.

Comment: So, what rebase does (I've never rebased...) is assign the current commit a specific name, in this case "master"? Plus, before today I have only used `git reset --hard` to reset local, unadded/uncommitted changes. What does `git reset --hard` do effectively here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to swap the branches `master` and `branch1`. You can do it in many ways. One of the easiest is to create a third (temporary) branch and use the same technique you use to swap the values of two variables (`tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp`).

Since you already have `branch2` that points to the same commit as `branch1` you can use it as the temporary branch (but do not delete it afterwards). In the variables swapping code above, `branch2` is `tmp`, `branch1` is `a` and `master` is `b`).

The `tmp = a` assignment already happened sometime in the past (`branch2` already points to the same commit as `branch1`). All you have to do are the branch operations equivalent to the other two assignment above.

One way to change where a branch points is to delete and re-create it. Another one is to use `reset --hard`. The delete & re-create way has a drawback: it breaks the link of `master` with the branch it tracks in the remote repository.

Let's do it the easy way:

```
# a = b (branch1 = master)
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard master
# Here branch1 moved to master

# b = tmp (master = branch2)
git checkout master
git reset --hard branch2
# Here master moved to branch2 (where branch1 was before too)
```

#### Warning!

Before everything else, make sure you don't have uncommitted changes. Any uncommitted change will be lost on `git reset --hard`.

If you have changes but you cannot commit them, [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them:

```
git stash
```

After you complete the swapping you can checkout `branch1` and unstash the changes to set the working tree in the same status as it was when you started the procedure:

```
git stash apply
```